# saving html tags and reproducing properly

Tags: php

I am using mysql db and PHP code.

I store value like this in db  `<u><strike><i><b>Opinion</b></i></strike></u>`

that is with some editor. so how do I display it so that, it takes all the tags given to it?

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Can you explain in more detail?

Comment: please show post an example what the result should look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always use `htmlspecialchars()` function when filling form values.
As well as textarea content.
It will preserve all your tags as is.

```
$text = htmlspecialchars($text);
echo "<textarea>$text</textarea>";
```